# How to configure two SMTP Server for wordpress

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, smtp

What I need is :

I need to send transactional e-mails from two SMTP configurations.

All WooCommerce side of e-mails should send from sales@mydomain.com.
Example: order summary, delivery status.

All WordPress user side of e-mails should send from support@mydomain.com.
Example: Forget password e-mail, account creation e-mail.

Note: All methods are working. I just want to send different e-mails from their respective purpose.

Comment: Are you really sending from two different domains i.e maydomain.com and mydomain.com? If it’s a typo you should update your question title, because you’re not trying to configure two SMTP servers, but rather two From addresses which is a _lot_ simpler

Comment: @Andy that was a typo. Sorry about that. But this not about from addresses. Same domain but I have two SMTP servers (main smtp server and marketing smtp server. Marketing smtp server is optimized send bulk emails)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: this is clumsy, someone might have a better suggestion. But here's one idea:

1. Leave WordPress configured with your support@mydomain.com settings.
2. Set up Woo with the sales@mydomain.com address (WooCommerce -> Settings -> Emails -> From Address).
3. Hook woocommerce_mail_callback with your own function that temporarily hooks phpmailer_init to change the SMTP configuration before calling wp_mail.

Or perhaps you can skip step 3 if your SMTP server can be configured to allow an alternate "from" address for authenticated users.

And just a heads up: WooCommerce supplies its own forgot password and new account emails, so you'd need to decide whether you want to return those to their WordPress defaults, or just change them as well in step 3.

Comment: +1 Thank you @Den Wich . I'm going to give a try on this idea.